# Is this a fake softeware update? How do I identify a process id of this dialogue?

Tags: update-manager, malware

[image: below:suspicious update notification, above: completed update check with software updater]

The dialogue shown in the bottom of the picture just came up. It looks unfamiliar, so I run software updater manually which completed and be seen in the above half of the picture.

The reasons the bottom dialogue is suspicious is because the title bar don't have the name of the program; not having usual software updater logo.

I try to check the validity of this dialogue. First thing I thought is to check the process id, see which file evoke it. But how do I do so? I can run `htop` but then I don't know what to search for.

Comment: `wmctrl -lp` will list the names of open windows and their PIDs.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Thank you, I think I just found out the origin file to be: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd`. This seemly is legit?

Comment: yes, it's legit.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Thank you very much. Just final update in case anyone is interested. Clicking "view" button brings up software center 'update' tab which it lists a hardware specific update.

Comment: I came across this week in this forum this program which turns the mouse cursor into cross hairs, then when you click on any window, it gets the process id    xprop | awk '/PID/ {print $3}'            also   xprop | grep WM_CLASS did something useful that I fogrget